# UIActivity won't show image?

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I'm trying to implement a custom UIActivity but it won't display my image. Here is what I'm trying to display:

[image: 59x59]

I made the "antenna and waves" with 10% opacity so that they would be displayed.

Here is what I got:

[image: Not what I expected]

How do I fix this? Does the opacity need to be 0% for the "antenna and waves"?

(icon size is 59x59 for iOS 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct, there should be alpha 0, exactly 0. for "anenna and waves". Also blue background for your icon is senseless - images for UIActivity has always just two parts: opaque and transparent.

Comment: basically the provided image is used like a mask.