# Uiactivty image Not Appearing in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am implementing `UIActivtyViewController`  and I want to add whatsApp image to that. (http://a598.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/fa/a8/02/faa80212-7d5b-f8a2-0e86-22d619ef6dc2/mzl.cmjuugpr.png) Adusted frame 60x60.

[image]
but I am  not getting As I excepted, I am getting like following message.

what i have to do display correct image thanks in advance.

Comment: add the 30 * 30 image

Comment: getting like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ympf5lbsm3hs4t/123.png

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios-6-7, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468978/how-can-i-add-a-activityitem-to-upper-activity-bar-in-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: this is wrkng but is it accepted by Apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891730/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-custom-uiactivity-displays-color-image-as-gray/22670582#22670582

Comment: i don't know clearly, but in my knowledge it is acceptable,

Answer (score 0):

You can only play with **transparency**. **Colors are ignored**. That's why you are getting a solid rectangle. Documentation says:

> The alpha channel of the image is used as a mask to generate the final
>   image that is presented to the user. Any color data in the image
>   itself is ignored.

Comment: is this solution is accepted by the Apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891730/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-custom-uiactivity-displays-color-image-as-gray/22670582#22670582

Comment: if not accpted, is there any other solutioni want to provide color image only

Comment: Your app might get rejected. The solution proposed in the thread you linked is using private APIs. However, you can give it a go and see if Apple approves it. If not, the only way of doing it is writing a custom activity sheet for sharing or using one of the 3rd party ones.