# Is there a way to get a reference of a UIActivity item view inside a UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

Let say I've a UIActivityViewController that I created with some UIActivity objects (e.g. a Share with Facebook activity).

When I present it, it'll show a component (don't know if a UIView or something else) for each UIActivity. What I want to accomplish is to put a tooltip on top of it.

[image]

Is there a way to get a reference to that "view" or component or to simply fetch the exact position on the screen (runtime)?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468978/how-can-i-add-a-activityitem-to-upper-activity-bar-in-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks Anbu but what I want to do is different: I don't want to move the position of the view but I want to find the coordinates of the view in the window